# U16C60D - Dual Series Connection Rectifier

Tags: diodes, rectifier

I can't find any replacement for the U16C60D rectifier. It is possible to put two seperate diodes (each at 8A/600V) in series like the "U16C60D" or inside the component it is not only just a two diodes in series (at least only to test the power supply if it works and then to put the original diode "U16C60D"?

Comment: in theory yes, but also no: https://www.daenotes.com/electronics/basic-electronics/diode-in-parallel

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes you can of course use discrete diodes in series configuration. Make sure voltage and current ratings are correct. Take thermals into account as well.

> I can't find any replacement for the U16C60D rectifier.

I don't know if you are trying to find the exact component but there are a few "possible alternatives" available (STPSC8TH13TI, STTH806TTI, DSP8-08A, etc). You can find alternatives from well-known distributors such as Digikey or Mouser.